# cant read json data esp 32 “parseObject() failed”

Tags: c++, esp32, json, java

> **hello  I am just trying to make Youtube Subscribe Counter with led matrix 32*8 and esp 32 and I had this problem when I trying to get
> subscribers to count
> so what is the problem and how I can fix it? `**

````
  ```    //########################  YouTube Subscriber Count Display on LED MATRIX  #############################
        // Receives and displays YouTube channel statistics
        //################# LIBRARIES ################
        String version = "v1.0";       // Version of this program
        
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
    #include <ArduinoJson.h>     // https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
    #include <Max72xxPanel.h>    // https://github.com/markruys/arduino-Max72xxPanel
    #include <time.h>
    //################ VARIABLES ################
    // Use your own API key by signing up for a free Youtube developer account at http://www.youtube.com
    // LED Matrix Pin -> ESP32 Pin
    // Vcc            -> 3v  
    // Gnd            -> Gnd 
    // DIN            -> MOSI pin use results of print statement 23 maybe
    // CS             -> SS pin   use results of print statement 5 maybe
    // CLK            -> SCK pin  use results of print statement 18 maybe
    
    const char* channelId = "UCqTSLaEj9c4hiZkU0FfbaJA"; // See your Channel details click on your channel icon at top-right, then Settings, then Advanced
    const char* apiKey    = "A--------------Aw"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started for an API key, you must enable it to make it work!
    const char* host      = "https://www.googleapis.com";
    unsigned long lastConnectionTime = 0;                 // Last time you connected to the server, in milliseconds
    const unsigned long  postingInterval = 10L*60L*1000L; // Delay between updates, in milliseconds, you should limit your YouTube requests per-day maximum
    
    //################ PROGRAM VARIABLES and OBJECTS ################
    int pinCS = 5; // Attach CS to this pin, DIN to MOSI and CLK to SCK (cf http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI )
    int numberOfHorizontalDisplays = 4;
    int numberOfVerticalDisplays   = 1;
    int wait   = 35; // In milliseconds
    int spacer = 1;
    int width  = 5 + spacer; // The font width is 5 pixels
    int port   = 443;
    String time_str;
    
    Max72xxPanel matrix = Max72xxPanel(pinCS, numberOfHorizontalDisplays, numberOfVerticalDisplays);
    
    struct channelStatistics{
      long viewCount;
      long commentCount;
      long subscriberCount;
      bool hiddenSubscriberCount;
      long videoCount;
    };
    
    // Change to your WiFi credentials
    const char* ssid     = "SSid";
    const char* password = "PASS";
    
    channelStatistics channelStats;
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200); // initialize serial communications
      Serial.println("Mosi="+String(MOSI));
      Serial.println("SS="+String(SS));
      Serial.println("SCK="+String(SCK));
      StartWiFi(ssid,password);
      StartTime();
    
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------
      configTime(0 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
      matrix.setIntensity(0); // Use a value between 0 and 15 for brightness
    // Adjust the LED matrix to your own needs
    //  matrix.setPosition(0, 0, 0); // The first display is at <0, 0>
    //  matrix.setPosition(1, 1, 0); // The second display is at <1, 0>
    //  matrix.setPosition(2, 2, 0); // The third display is at <2, 0>
    //  matrix.setPosition(3, 3, 0); // And the last display is at <3, 0>
    //  ...
      matrix.setRotation(0, 1);    // The first display is position is rotated
      matrix.setRotation(1, 1);    // The first display is position is rotated
      matrix.setRotation(2, 1);    // The first display is position is rotated
      matrix.setRotation(3, 1);    // The first display is position is rotated
      lastConnectionTime = millis();
      obtain_subscriber_stats();
    }
    
    void loop() {
      display_message("Subs: " + String(channelStats.subscriberCount));
      time_t now = time(nullptr);
      String time = String(ctime(&now));
      time.trim();
      display_message(" on " + time);
      if (millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval) { // 15-minutes
        obtain_subscriber_stats();
        lastConnectionTime = millis();
      }
    }
    
    //################ PROGRAM FUNCTIONS ################
    
    void display_message(String message){ // Scroll the image left
      matrix.fillScreen(LOW);
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < width * message.length() + matrix.width() - 1 - spacer; i++ ) {
        int letter = i / width;
        int x = (matrix.width() - 1) - i % width;
        int y = (matrix.height() - 8) / 2; // center the text vertically
        while ( x + width - spacer >= 0 && letter >= 0 ) {
          if (letter < message.length()) matrix.drawChar(x, y, message[letter], HIGH, LOW, 1); // HIGH means foreground on, LOW means background off, LOW< HIGH inverts the display
          letter--;
          x -= width;
        }
        matrix.write(); // Send bitmap to display
        delay(wait);
      }
    }
    
    void obtain_subscriber_stats() {
      String command = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" + String(channelId);
      String response = GetRequestFromYoutube(command);       
      StaticJsonBuffer <200> jsonBuffer;
      JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response); // Parse JSON
      if (!root.success()) {
        Serial.println(F("jsonBuffer.parseObject() failed"));
      }
      else
      {
        
        JsonObject& current                = root["items"][0]["statistics"];  
        long subscriberCount               = current["subscriberCount"];
        long viewCount                     = current["viewCount"];
        long commentCount                  = current["commentCount"];
        long hiddenSubscriberCount         = current["hiddenSubscriberCount"];
        long videoCount                    = current["videoCount"];
        channelStats.viewCount             = viewCount;
        channelStats.subscriberCount       = subscriberCount;
        channelStats.commentCount          = commentCount;
        channelStats.hiddenSubscriberCount = hiddenSubscriberCount;
        channelStats.videoCount            = videoCount;
       
        
      }  
      Serial.println("      View Count = " + String(channelStats.viewCount));
      Serial.println("Subscriber Count = " + String(channelStats.subscriberCount));
        Serial.println(GetRequestFromYoutube(command));
        Serial.println(response);
      //  Serial.println(jsonBuffer.parseObject(response));
    
    }
    
    String GetRequestFromYoutube(String request) {
      String headers, body = "";
      bool Headers    = false;
      bool currentLineIsBlank = true;
      int  MessageLength = 1000;
      // Connect with youtube api over ssl
      WiFiClientSecure client;
      if (client.connect(host, port)) {
        Serial.println(".... connected to server");
        char c;
        int ch_count=0;
        request += "&key=" + String(apiKey);
        request = "GET " + request;
        Serial.println(request);
        client.println(request);
        int now   = millis();
        while (millis()-now < 1500) {
          while (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();
            if(!Headers){
              if (currentLineIsBlank && c == '\n') {
                Headers = true;
              }
              else{
                headers = headers + c;
              }
            } else {
              if (ch_count < MessageLength)  {
                body = body+c;
                ch_count++;
              }
            }
            if (c == '\n') {
              currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } else if (c != '\r') {
              currentLineIsBlank = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return body;
    }
    
    ////////////// WiFi, Time and Date Functions /////////////////
    int StartWiFi(const char* ssid, const char* password) {
      int connAttempts = 0;
      Serial.print(F("\r\nConnecting to: ")); Serial.println(String(ssid));
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
        delay(500); Serial.print(".");
        if (connAttempts > 20) {
          Serial.println("\nFailed to connect to a Wi-Fi network");
          return -5;
        }
        connAttempts++;
      }
      Serial.print(F("WiFi connected at: "));
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      return 1;
    }
    
    void StartTime(){
      configTime(0, 0, "0.uk.pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
      setenv("TZ", "GMT0BST,M3.5.0/01,M10.5.0/02",1); // Change for your location
      UpdateLocalTime();
    }
    
    void UpdateLocalTime(){
      struct tm timeinfo;
      while (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
        Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
      }
      //See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/
      Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%a %b %d %Y   %H:%M:%S"); // Displays: Saturday, June 24 2017 14:05:49
      char output[50];
      strftime(output, 50, "%a %d-%b-%y  (%H:%M:%S)", &timeinfo);
      time_str = output;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: why are you not providing all information? ... I am very certain that the error message is longer than `parseObject() failed`

Comment: this is the full problem if you read the code you will find this if statment
``` JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(response); // Parse JSON
      if (!root.success()) {
        Serial.println(F("jsonBuffer.parseObject() failed"));
      }```
it just printing this message in the serial monitor

Comment: print the content and take a look at the byre json. It's probably either too long too fit into 200 bytes or the formating is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for ArduinoJson 5](https://arduinojson.org/v5/faq/why-parsing-fails/) lists the reasons why [`parseObject()`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/parseobject/) may return `false`:

1. The input is not a valid JSON
2. The [`StaticJsonBuffer`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/) is too small
3. The [`StaticJsonBuffer`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/) is too big (stack overflow)
4. The [`DynamicJsonBuffer`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/) fails to allocate memory
5. You called [`parseObject()`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/parseobject/) instead of [`parseArray()`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/parsearray/)
6. The nesting limit is too low

A glance at your code suggests that the problem is number 2: the [`StaticJsonBuffer`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/) is too small.
Indeed, I don't know what the input looks like, but 200 bytes is probably too small to store the result.

You can use the [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v5/assistant/) to compute the required capacity for the [`JsonBuffer`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/). Don't forget to switch to a [`DynamicJsonBuffer`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonbuffer/) if it becomes bigger than 4 KB.

Lastly, I really recommend that you switch to [ArduinoJson 6](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/upgrade/) because it offers more features, better performance, better memory usage, and better error reporting, all with the same code size and portability.